# How to select value in selectbox using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a selectbox , say cars and it has values already eg.

1. Hyundai
2. Benz
3. BMW

now I want to select the value using plain dojo (not dijit. How can I achieve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`var element = document.getElementById('cars');
 element.value = 'Hyundai';`

in Dojo <1.7

`dojo.attr(dojo.byId('cars'),'value','Hyundai')`

in Dojo > 1.7

`domAttr.set(dojo.byId('cars'),'value','Hyundai');`